# Want to count the number of time a particular file is included - php

Tags: php

Actually I am modifying an old script of my client made by some other developer, what he did is, he included same file many times like a `config file`, that is causing some variables overwrites, I just want to count how many times a particular file is included in complete page execution, like how many times config file is loaded and even better if I can get the line numbers and file names of where those files are included.

If there is any way to get this done, that will help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use xdebug for this kind of job.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- "Files that are included or required multiple times only show up once in the returned array."

Comment: You can profile the script execution by Xdebug's profiling. by this way you can find out more. Here is a full guide for this. [Profiling PHP scripts](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Comment: @rjdown It was just a suggestion. If it helps them, *great!*

Comment: As for a simpler measure and since this is for debugging purposes only(?), you could set a global counter variable to 0 at the begin of your main script, have your include file increase the value by one, and check the value at the end of your main script … Of course that won’t catch cases of includes that are “inactive” due to being placed inside unfulfilled conditions, uncalled functions etc. … but I am not sure whether xdebug would catch those either.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, this would be best done in the included file itself. Add a line, such as `track_inclusion(__FILE__);` at the start of it. Define the function like so:

```
function track_inclusion($filename=null) {
    static $inclusions = array();
    if( !$filename) return $inclusions;

    if( !isset($inclusions[$filename])) $inclusions[$filename] = array();
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($trace as $t) {
        if( !preg_match("/^(?:include|require)(?:_once)?$/i",$t['function'])) continue;

        $inclusions[$filename][] = $t;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then, once you're all done, you can call `track_inclusion()` to retrieve the inclusion data and `var_dump` it out to have a look - once you see the structure it gives you, you could present it in a more meaningful way.

Comment: Let me try this, will let you know the output.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for but I used @CBroe idea coz that was easy and enough for me, no doubt this answer provides more details. Thanks all.